# Fastest and most cost efficient way to copy over an S3 bucket from another AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket that is 9TB and I want to copy it over to another AWS account.

What would  be the fastest and most cost efficient way to copy it?

I know I can rsync them and also use S3 replication.

Rsync I think will take too long and I think be a bit pricey.

I have not played with S3 replication so I am not sure of its speed and cost.

Are there any other methods that I might not be aware of?

FYI - The source and destination buckets will be in the same region (but different accounts).

Answer (score 0):

There is no quicker way to do it then using sync and I do not believe it is that pricey. You do not mention the number of files you are copying though.

You will pay $0.004 / 10,000 requests on the GET operations on the files you are copying and then $0.005 / 1,000 requests on the PUT operations on the files you are writing. Also, I believe you won't pay data transfer costs if this is in the same region.

If you want to speed this up you could use multiple sync jobs if the bucket has a way of being logically divisible i.e. s3://examplebucket/job1 and s3://examplebucket/job2

Answer (score 0):

You can use [S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/batch-ops.html) to copy large quantities of objects between buckets *in the same region*.

It can accept a CSV file containing a list of objects, or you can use the output of [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.

While copying, it can also update tags, metadata and ACLs.

See: [Cross-account bulk transfer of files using Amazon S3 Batch Operations | AWS Storage Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/cross-account-bulk-transfer-of-files-using-amazon-s3-batch-operations/)

Answer (score 0):

I wound up finding the page below and used replication with the copy to itself method.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-large-transfer-between-buckets/